# Trouble reading from text file using redirection and getline

Tags: c++, getline

I'm writing a basic encoding algorithm in c++ that shifts and sorts a string to compress it. I've created a function called insertionSortEncode(input) that encodes a text file from redirection line by line.

The program will be executed in the following way:

```
encode insertion <ex1.txt> encoded_ex1.txt
```

I want to be able to traverse ex1.txt line by line and encode each line using the insertionSortEncode algorithm I have created.

The following implementation that I have tried results in SegFaults:

```
string input;
while (getline(cin, input)){
        cout << insertionSortEncode(input) << endl;
    }
```

I tested to see if the issues came from the encoding method, however, trying various hardcoded inputs resulted in no errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `cout << input << endl;` instead of `cout << insertionSortEncode(input) << endl;` as a debugging step

Comment: With that said the segfault is most likely a bug in `insertionSortEncode()`